# Large Collection Exhausting Memory

Tags: magento2, collection

I am writing an admin module. I created a collection and if the number of rows in the table are small it loads fine. Ultimately the table will have 250k rows in it and when I attempt to load the collection it exhausts memory. I was under the impression that Magento would lazy load collections. I also will probably need to know how to use the resource iterator in mage 2 as well. I can provide code samples but there is little more than a basic module skeleton at this point. I would greatly appreciate a code example of how to handle and iterate through a large collection.

Note: the collection is pulling from a custom table

#### Controller:

```
<?php
namespace Customer\Customerimportexport\Controller\Adminhtml\Import;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Customer\Customerimportexport\Model\WebcustomersFactory;

class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{

    protected $_modelWebcustomersFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        WebcustomersFactory $modelWebcustomersFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_modelWebcustomersFactory = $modelWebcustomersFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {

        $webcustomersModel = $this->_modelWebcustomersFactory->create();

        // Get webcustomers collection
        $webcustomersCollection = $webcustomersModel->getCollection();

        // Load all data of collection
        foreach ($webcustomersModel->getCollection() as $key => $webcustomer) {
            var_dump($webcustomer->getData());
            die();
        }

        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }

}
```

#### Model

```
<?php

namespace Customer\Customerimportexport\Model;

use \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;

class Webcustomers extends AbstractModel
{
    /**
     * Define resource model
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Customer\Customerimportexport\Model\ResourceModel\Webcustomers');
    }
}
```

#### Resource Model

```
<?php

namespace Customer\Customerimportexport\Model\ResourceModel;

class Webcustomers extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb
{
    /**
     * Define main table
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('web_customers', 'entity_id');
    }
}
```

#### Collection

```
<?php 

namespace Customer\Customerimportexport\Model\ResourceModel\Webcustomers;

use \Magento\Framework\Model\Resource\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;

class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
{
    /**
     * Define model & resource model
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(
            'Customer\Customerimportexport\Model\Webcustomers',
            'Customer\Customerimportexport\Model\ResourceModel\Webcustomers'
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you already tried with repositories instead of collections?

Comment: Post a sample of the code and we can see if there is anything going on.

Comment: @RyanStreet I posted the controller, model, resource model and collection. I get memory exhausted at the var_dump.

Comment: @RiccardoT I am looking into it now, I never heard of it before.

Comment: Well.. you updated your code. IMHO your problem is the var_dump itself

Comment: @RiccardoT if I remove the var_dump, attempt to echo out one field and then quit the loop I get the same behavior. Conversely if I load the data from the table just using objectmanager and a plain query it works just fine

Comment: You commented that `setPageSize()` did not help. Please update your question with that code because as it stands now, this seems to be the problem and you probably used it in the wrong way.

Comment: So I removed any misleading code I left in that confused the issue. This code when loading data from a table with 250k rows will exhaust the memory on the server where it runs. Ultimately I thought magento would lazy load the rows as it parses the result set but it doesn't seem to. As soon as it dumps the first record it fails. Conversely if I load the data using Zend DB objects and a plain query it works just fine. Something is amiss. Now I have done virtually the same thing in Mage 1 and did not have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably your culprit:  `var_dump($webcustomersCollection->count());`

That loads the entire collection (of all records in the table) to get the count.  The loop does the same thing.

Apply some filters to your collection before looping.

There is some more that needs to be cleaned up with this code, (dependency injection, rendering output, etc.), but that's an answer for a different question.

Comment: Also, if you need to simply get the count, at least in M1 (don't know about M2), there was a way to get special count SQL instead of loading the entire collection.

Comment: @KevinSchroeder, correct, (it is `getSize()`) and it is present in M2 :)

Comment: Actually I only had the line there as I was trying to figure out if I could limit/paginate through the results but I had the problem before adding it

Comment: Note: even if I limit the collection - ->setPageSize(20)->setCurPage(1); I still run out of memory. The only way it works is if I limit (e.g. delete) the number of rows in the table down.